# SQLAlchemy using a JOIN Table

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

I apologize for the lengthy post but I am trying to figure out my problem and need to provide all the code to figure out where I am going wrong. I am trying to return the following data set using SQLAlchemy with FastAPI + Pydantic but keep getting an error.

**Error**

```
fastapi.exceptions.ResponseValidationError: 18 validation errors:
  {'type': 'missing', 'loc': ('response', 0, 'role', 'permissions', 0, 'name'), 'msg': 'Field required', 'input': <src.schemas.roles_permissions.RolesPermissions object at 0x7ff3001e72b0>, 'url': 'https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.5/v/missing'}
  {'type': 'missing', 'loc': ('response', 0, 'role', 'permissions', 0, 'slug'), 'msg': 'Field required', 'input': <src.schemas.roles_permissions.RolesPermissions object at 0x7ff3001e72b0>, 'url': 'https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.5/v/missing'}
  {'type': 'missing', 'loc': ('response', 0, 'role', 'permissions', 0, 'description'), 'msg': 'Field required', 'input': <src.schemas.roles_permissions.RolesPermissions object at 0x7ff3001e72b0>, 'url': 'https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.5/v/missing'}
```

This is the object I am trying to return based on the Pydantic models.

**Return Object**

```
[
  {
    "uuid": "86c1f82b-5f3f-4294-a1b8-096ecdc78f9f",
    "id": 0,
    "created_at": "2023-11-18T06:14:01.214Z",
    "updated_at": "2023-11-18T06:14:01.214Z",
    "role_uuid": "stringstringstringstringstringstring",
    "firstname": "string",
    "lastname": "string",
    "email": "user@example.com",
    "active": 1,
    "role": {
      "uuid": "86c1f82b-5f3f-4294-a1b8-096ecdc78f9f",
      "id": 0,
      "created_at": "2023-11-18T06:14:01.214Z",
      "updated_at": "2023-11-18T06:14:01.214Z",
      "name": "string",
      "slug": "string",
      "description": "string",
      "active": 1,
      "permissions": [
        {
          "uuid": "86c1f82b-5f3f-4294-a1b8-096ecdc78f9f",
          "id": 0,
          "created_at": "2023-11-18T06:14:01.214Z",
          "updated_at": "2023-11-18T06:14:01.214Z",
          "name": "string",
          "slug": "string",
          "description": "string",
          "active": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Here are my SQLAlchemy database schemas.

**Database Schemas**

```
class Permissions(Base):
    __tablename__ = "permissions"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    uuid: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(36), nullable=False)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(64), nullable=False)
    slug: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(64), nullable=False)
    description: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String, nullable=False)
    active: Mapped[bool] = mapped_column(Boolean(True), nullable=False, default=True)
    created_at: Mapped[datetime] = mapped_column(DateTime, nullable=False, default=func.now())
    updated_at: Mapped[datetime] = mapped_column(DateTime, nullable=False, default=func.now())

class Roles(Base):
    __tablename__ = "roles"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    uuid: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(36), nullable=False)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(64), nullable=False)
    slug: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(64), nullable=False)
    description: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String, nullable=True, default=None)
    active: Mapped[bool] = mapped_column(Boolean(True), nullable=False, default=True)
    created_at: Mapped[datetime] = mapped_column(DateTime, nullable=False, default=func.now())
    updated_at: Mapped[datetime] = mapped_column(DateTime, nullable=False, default=func.now())

    permissions: Mapped[list["RolesPermissions"]] = relationship()

class RolesPermissions(Base):
    __tablename__ = "roles_permissions"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    role_uuid: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(36), ForeignKey("roles.uuid"), nullable=False)
    permission_uuid: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(36), ForeignKey("permissions.uuid"), nullable=False)
    created_at: Mapped[datetime] = mapped_column(DateTime, nullable=False, default=func.now())
    updated_at: Mapped[datetime] = mapped_column(DateTime, nullable=False, default=func.now())

    permission = relationship("Permissions", foreign_keys=[permission_uuid])

class Users(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    uuid: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(36), nullable=False)
    role_uuid: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(36), ForeignKey("roles.uuid"), nullable=False)
    firstname: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(32), nullable=False)
    lastname: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(32), nullable=False)
    email: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(128), nullable=False)
    password: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(128), nullable=False)
    active: Mapped[bool] = mapped_column(Boolean(True), nullable=False, default=True)
    created_at: Mapped[datetime] = mapped_column(DateTime, nullable=False, default=func.now())
    updated_at: Mapped[datetime] = mapped_column(DateTime, nullable=False, default=func.now())

    role: Mapped["Roles"] = relationship(foreign_keys=[role_uuid])
```

When I use the following and try to pass the data set to be returned I get the original error:

```
results = session.scalars(select(Users).order_by(Users.firstname)).all()
```

**Pydantic Models**

```
class PermissionBaseModel(BaseModel):
    name: str = Field(
        max_length=64,
        min_length=2
    )
    slug: str = Field(
        max_length=64,
        min_length=1
    )
    description: str = Field()
    active: bool = Field(
        default=1
    )

    model_config = ConfigDict(extra="ignore", from_attributes=True)


class PermissionModel(PermissionBaseModel, CreatedUpdatedAtModel, IDModel, UUIDModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(extra="ignore", from_attributes=True)


class RoleBaseModel(BaseModel):
    name: str = Field(
        max_length=64,
        min_length=2
    )
    slug: str = Field(
        max_length=64,
        min_length=1
    )
    description: str = Field()
    active: bool = Field(
        default=1
    )

    model_config = ConfigDict(extra="ignore", from_attributes=True)


class RoleModel(RoleBaseModel, CreatedUpdatedAtModel, IDModel, UUIDModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(extra="ignore", from_attributes=True)


class RolePermissionModel(RoleModel):
    permissions: list[PermissionModel]


class UserBaseModel(BaseModel):
    role_uuid: str = Field(
        max_length=36,
        min_length=36
    )
    firstname: constr(strip_whitespace=True) = Field(
        max_length=32,
        min_length=2
    )
    lastname: constr(strip_whitespace=True) = Field(
        max_length=32,
        min_length=2
    )
    email: EmailStr = Field(
        max_length=128
    )
    active: bool = Field(
        default=1
    )

    model_config = ConfigDict(extra="ignore", from_attributes=True)


class UserModel(UserBaseModel, CreatedUpdatedAtModel, IDModel, UUIDModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(extra="ignore", from_attributes=True)


class UserCreateModel(UserBaseModel):
    password: str = Field(
        min_length=8
    )

    model_config = ConfigDict(extra="ignore", from_attributes=True)


class UserPasswordModel(BaseModel):
    password: str = Field(
        min_length=8
    )
    password_new: str = Field(
        min_length=8
    )

    model_config = ConfigDict(extra="ignore", from_attributes=True)


class UserWithRolePermissionsModel(UserModel):
    role: RolePermissionModel


class CreatedUpdatedAtModel(BaseModel):
    created_at: Union[datetime, None] = Field(
        default=None
    )
    updated_at: Union[datetime, None] = Field(
        default=None
    )


class UUIDModel(BaseModel):
    uuid: str = Field(
        default=uuid4(),
        max_length=36,
        min_length=36
    )


class IDModel(BaseModel):
    id: int = Field(
        default=0
    )
```

**Route**

```
@routes.get(
    "",
    status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK,
    responses={
        status.HTTP_200_OK: {
            "model": list[UserWithRolePermissionsModel],
            "description": "OK",
        }
    },
    response_model=list[UserWithRolePermissionsModel],
    dependencies=[Depends(AuthHandler(["admin:users:get"]))]
)
async def get(session: Session = Depends(get_session)) -> list[UserWithRolePermissionsModel]:
    return controller_user.get(session)
```

**Service / Controller**

```
    def get(session):
        try:
            results = session.scalars(select(Users).order_by(Users.firstname)).all()

            for user in results:
                print(user.__dict__)

            return results
        except Exception as error:
            Logger.error(error)

            return False
```

Basically, how in the world do I use a `JOIN` table with SQLAlchemy? The fields it is looking for belong to `Permissions` not `RolesPermissions`. I do not care to return `RolesPermissions`, just the `Role` and the `Permissions` for that role.

Thank you!

Comment: `ResponseValidationError` means what you're returning cant be converted to your response Pydantic model, so you need to share those.

Comment: Please add your endpoint function code

Comment: Your pydantic response model isn't valid, related to your output

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html#simplifying-association-objects

Comment: @MotovYurii - I have added the route as well as controller / service code.

Comment: @AshkanGolehPour The Pydantic models have been added, my apologies.

Comment: @M.O. The Pydantic models have been added.

Comment: You seem to have mixed up the `RolesPermissions` and `Permissions` database models. When FastAPI converts your database models to oydantic models, your `PermissionModel` pydantic model expects a `Permissions` object, but it gets a `RolesPermissions`.